# hierarchy or one directory

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, directory, system-administration

I'm working on an application that will (hopefully) store large amount of media.

I've been looking at two possible ways to store the data in directories.

Hierarchical

```
 Data
├── 123
│   ├── 456
│   │   ├── 789
│   │   │   ├── track1.mp3
│   │   │   ├── track2.mp3
│   │   │   ├── track3.mp3
│   │   │   ├── track4.mp3
│   │   │   ├── track5.mp3
│   │   │   └── track6.mp3
```

Or storing all the files in one directory and naming each of the files after it's database id

```
67.mp3 68.mp3
```

Lets say I'll have 300,000 files. What are the pros and cons for each way of storing the data?

Comment: if using AWS S3 buckets, then there are other options

Comment: Are you using S3? or where are you planning on storing these files?

Comment: I'm not using S3, but that's a good idea. I was also interested in peoples opinions on the matter.

Comment: If you are going to use AWS any, you'd be fool hardy not to at least consider employing S3 for this type of storage - fast, cheap and redundant...what else could you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are planning on using S3, read this question at the link below and in particular my answer. I don't want to repeat it all here; better to keep the answer in one place.

[Amazon AWS S3 directory structure efficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167125/amazon-aws-s3-directory-structure-efficiency/22173939#22173939)